# How to transform a list of dicts

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have a list of dicts:

```
[{'prox', 'SIN'},
 {'SIN', 'nerps'},
 {'SIN', 'malzon'},
 {'SIN', 'oportun'},
 {'ANAT', 'head'},
 {'ANAT', 'eyes'}]
```

How can I transform this list to get this as output:

```
[{'SIN':['prox','nerps','malzon','oportun'],'ANAT':['head','eyes']}
```

I tried this approach, but it's not working:

```
d ={}
for dictionary in l:
    for key, (k, v) in dictionary.items:
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = {}
        d[key][k] = v
```

But it fails because `set has no items method`
When I iterate over all dicts inside the list, it becomes a set thatI don't know how to use it.

Comment: The initial data is not a `list` of `dict` but a `list` of `set`. It is the reason why you get this error message telling you that you cannot call `items` on a `set`. You should precise in your question if the initial data should be a `list` of `set` or a `list` of `dict` because the solution is not same.

Answer (score 1):

> ```py
> [{'prox', 'SIN'},
> {'SIN', 'nerps'},
> {'SIN', 'malzon'},
> {'SIN', 'oportun'},
> {'ANAT', 'head'},
> {'ANAT', 'eyes'}]
> ```

This is not a list of dict, this is a list of Sets. This changes everything, you can't use `dictionary.items` and even if you could, don't forget the parentheses `dictionary.items()`.

If you know that you will always have an uppercase and a lowercase word, you can just sort them and add them to a dict.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for i, j in (sorted(e) for e in dictionary):
    d[i].append(j)
```